# Read Operating System messages - stand-by

Tags: java

How to read Operating System messages?

Is Java capable of listening to the Operating System Messages from Java API? I want to be notified when the OS (In my case Windows) goes to Stand by, Hibernate states. Please suggest a possible way.

Answer (score 2):

That is a very low level Operating System functionality. Java has no chance of noticing this happening. In fact, since your applications would be running on Ring 3, there's no chance of detecting this regardless of the programming language.

Your application would need to run on the more privileged rings, where device drivers and the kernel runs, in order to respond to sleep states.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kayaman. Is there any workaround at least?

Comment: No, not really. It's not something that your program is supposed to know or care about. Why do you think you need to know about the sleep states?